# Change Color of Image Based on Shape Covering It

Tags: ios, objective-c, opengl-es, shader, mask

Let say i have three objects. One is shaped like a circle. The other is shaped like half a circle. And the last one is shaped like a thin rectangle

A - circle

B - half circle

C - thin rectangle

[image]

1.) I use A as my base. I put B on top of it covering half of A. Then i put C on top of both of them.

2.) I change the visible color of A (considering the shapes on top of it)

3.) I remove B and C and A's color should look like there are purple slices.

Does anyone here know how this could be done in objective-c? Is there even a way to do this? Should i be using open-gl for this? If yes, how?

Comment: If you are just drawing shapes on top of each other, with the color in the final image being the same color as the top-most image, you can use CoreGraphics library. Check the api
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/Introduction/Introduction.html